# Bootstrap grid class combined with other class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have this class that I downloaded from the internet called `.slideanim`.

Also, i'm using the bootstrap grid class, how can I combin both of them?

When i'm trying space between then it doesn't work.

Html:

```
<div style="position: relative" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-push-4">
    <div class="hovereffect">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="../User/Pictures/ShirtCheck.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2>Add to cart</h2>
                <p class="icon-links">
                    <a href="#">Text</a>
                </p>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.slideanim {visibility:hidden;}
.slide {
    /* The name of the animation */
    animation-name: slide;
    -webkit-animation-name: slide; 
    /* The duration of the animation */
    animation-duration: 1s; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    /* Make the element visible */
    visibility: visible; 
}

/* Go from 0% to 100% opacity (see-through) and specify the percentage from when to slide in the element along the Y-axis */
@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
    } 
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    } 
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
    } 
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}
```

Script:

```
<script>     

  $(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".slideanim").each(function(){
  var pos = $(this).offset().top;

    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (pos < winTop + 600) {
      $(this).addClass("slide");
    }
  });
});
      </script>
```

What I have tried:

```
<div style="position: relative" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-push-4 slideanim">
        <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="../User/Pictures/ShirtCheck.png" alt="">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <h2>Add to cart</h2>
                    <p class="icon-links">
                        <a href="#">Text</a>
                    </p>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Place your script just before closing `</body>` tag and it will work if jQuery is attached. https://jsfiddle.net/kd9dx5vs/

Comment: @Muhammad Usman Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Check fiddle, Its working there..